# How would I type a server response that could look different?

Tags: typescript

I'm querying a server that can respond with either

```
interface Response {
  [id: string]: Data
}
```

or

```
interface Response {
  error: string
}
```

but I get the following error: `Property 'error' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type '{ /* Structure of Data */ }'.`

How should this be typed?

Comment: Name your "error" interface something like `CommonResponse` and make your other interface inherit it: `interface Response extends CommonResponse`.

Comment: The error you get here is because type `string` does not match type `Data`. The response requires everything to be of type `Data`. You could just say the type can be `Data | string` in the `Response` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define server response type as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of data response and error response:

```
interface DataResponse {
    [id: string]: Data
}

interface ErrorResponse {
    error: string
}

type ServerResponse = DataResponse | ErrorResponse;
```

Comment: It looks union type behaves like a multiple inheritance, if I understood correctly. Interesting!!!

Comment: @Alisson, no it is not. Variable defined as `ServerResponse` can be either `DataResponse`  **OR** `ErrorResponse`. [Intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) is closer to multiple inheritance

Comment: Oh, my bad, I need to learn `TypeScript`, it looks they introduced new concepts I'm not used (I mostly worked with C# and javascript). Thanks for your answer.